# Meaning of " will have to do"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Could you tell what does this construction mean in the following extract "At the time of writing, however, it is available only in Russian, so an outline of some of the details from the film will have to do". Sounds strange.

Answer (score 1):

More context would be helpful, so we can understand what *it" refers to. Without it, I would guess it means that the film is available only in Russian, so all we can give you is a partial outline.

The term ***to do*** in "will have to do" means:

> 30. to serve or be satisfactory, as for the purpose; be enough; suffice:
>       http://www.dictionary.com/browse/do

Comment: Thanks ,Yes, it means film , but it sounds strange to me nevertheless, I think it betterto say " will do" , what does "will have to "imply ?

Comment: It means that there is nothing better, so this will have to do. It's a common phrase - see, for example: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10031/the-meaning-of-will-have-to-do or http://www.idioms4you.com/complete-idioms/will-have-to-do.html

Answer (score 0):

**Will have to do** means that it is the best/most that can be offered. The sentence can be reworded without change of meaning: Because the film is only available in Russian, the reader *will have to be content* with an outline of some details.